# NullPointerException on a simple Android app

Tags: java, android

I'm building a simple idle game, and I have absolutely no idea why it's crashing. This is the code:

```
package com.de_velopers.idlegame;import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public int money;
    public int upgrade_perClick_multiplier;
    public int upgrade_perclick_level;
    public int upgrade_perclick_cost;
    public int upgrade_perclick_effect;
    String stringmoney = String.valueOf(money);
    TextView amount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.moneyView);
    String upgradeCostString = String.valueOf(upgrade_perclick_cost);
    TextView upgradeCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.upgrade_pc_cost);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        upgrade_perclick_level = 1;
        upgrade_perclick_cost = upgrade_perclick_level * 3;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void increment(View view){
        if (upgrade_perclick_level < 2) {
            money = money + 1;
        }else money = money + upgrade_perClick_multiplier;
        amount.setText(stringmoney);

    }

    public void upgrade_perclick_buy(View view) {
        if (money >= upgrade_perclick_cost) {
            money = money - upgrade_perclick_cost;
            upgrade_perclick_level = upgrade_perclick_level + 1;
            upgrade_perclick_cost = upgrade_perClick_multiplier * 4;
            upgrade_perClick_multiplier = upgrade_perClick_multiplier * 2;
            String upgradeAmnt = String.valueOf(upgrade_perClick_multiplier);
            TextView upgradeEffect = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.clickAmnt);
            upgradeEffect.setText(upgradeAmnt);
            amount.setText(stringmoney);
            upgradeCost.setText(upgradeCostString);
        }else;
    }
}
```

And the error I'm getting is this

```
   08-22 00:50:14.968  32347-32347/com.de_velopers.idlegame E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.de_velopers.idlegame, PID: 32347
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.de_velopers.idlegame/com.de_velopers.idlegame.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1921)
            at com.de_velopers.idlegame.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:19)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Apparently it's because of line 19 but line 19 looks fine to me...
    TextView amount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.moneyView);

Edit: Can I ask why I'm being downvoted? Yeah it was due me overlooking something but why is this a bad post? Not enough detail? Am I too stupid to be asking questions?

Comment: Shouldn't the app be created first before you access its views?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This `TextView upgradeCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.upgrade_pc_cost);` instantiates a field in the class. This means the code is executed **BEFORE** the `onCreate()` method, so the layout is not set and you get the NPE.

Comment: To combat this, have a field called TextView upgradeCost and set its value after the onCreate() so that you avoid the NPE.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `findViewById()` in the declaration of a class member. it will be called before the layout is set. You have to call this only after calling `setContentView()`.

```
TextView amount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView amount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.moneyView)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use findViewById before you invoke setContentView.because before that,your layout is not inflated into your activity.

just move all your findViewById after setContentView, It will work.

note the field you declared with a expression,the expression always run before onCreate method,the field asignment expression is calculated when the activity instance was creating.